# Message will prompt if he closes the program

Tags: java, cmd, message

How will be the syntax in java if someone try to run a java program in a CMD then if he close the CMD, there will be a message or prevent the user to close the program.

Comment: It is bad programming practise to try to prevent the user from closing a program. This is the user's choice, not yours.

Comment: @Delan: So what do you call the ubiquitous »You have unsaved work. Close anyway?« message boxes? ;-) (Granted, those are hallmarks of poor design, anyway.)

Comment: That's a specific case where it's a confirmation where the user has unsaved changes. However, from the asker's post, I only understood that it was desired to *prevent the user to close the program* (sic)

Comment: I don't want an embarassing last message if I hit the "Boss Key"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a console application as the OS will simply close the console and terminate your process. In GUI applications there usually are events that are fired when a window is closed which you could intercept.